# Why does SQL server passes a value to a OUTPUT variable in a stored procedure?

Tags: c++, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, odbc

I have a function which calls a stored procedure with providing its parameters.

```
int8 CDBAgent::CreateKnights(uint16 sClanID, uint8 bNation, string & strKnightsName, string & strChief, uint8 bFlag)
{
    int8 bRet = -1;
    unique_ptr<OdbcCommand> dbCommand(m_GameDB->CreateCommand());
    if (dbCommand.get() == nullptr)
        return bRet;


    dbCommand->AddParameter(SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT, &bRet);
    dbCommand->AddParameter(SQL_PARAM_INPUT, strKnightsName.c_str(), strKnightsName.length());
    dbCommand->AddParameter(SQL_PARAM_INPUT, strChief.c_str(), strChief.length());

    if (!dbCommand->Execute(string_format(_T("{? = CALL CREATE_KNIGHTS ( %d, %d, %d, ?, ?)}"), sClanID, bNation, bFlag)))
        ReportSQLError(m_GameDB->GetError());


    return bRet;
}
```

and the stored procedure;

```
USE [KN_online]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[CREATE_KNIGHTS]    Script Date: 09/04/2016 03:09:46 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- Batch submitted through debugger: SQLQuery4.sql|7|0|C:\Users\Leth\AppData\Local\Temp\~vs3286.sql

/****** Object:  Stored Procedure dbo.CREATE_KNIGHTS    Script Date: 6/6/2006 6:03:32 PM ******/

-- modify by sungyong 2002.09.27

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CREATE_KNIGHTS]
@nRet       smallint OUTPUT,
@index      smallint,
@nation     tinyint,
@community  tinyint,
@strName    char(21), 
@strChief   char(21)


AS

DECLARE @Row tinyint, @knightsindex smallint, @knightsname char(21)
    SET @Row = 0    SET @knightsindex = 0  SET @knightsname = ''

    SELECT @Row = COUNT(*) FROM KNIGHTS WHERE IDNum = @index or  IDName = @strName

    IF @Row > 0 or @index = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @nRet =  3
        RETURN
    END

    --SELECT @Row = COUNT(*) FROM KNIGHTS WHERE IDName = @strName

    --IF @Row > 0
--  BEGIN
    --  SET @nRet =  3
        --RETURN
--  END

BEGIN TRAN  

    INSERT INTO KNIGHTS ( IDNum, Nation, Flag, IDName, Chief  ) 
    VALUES   (@index, @nation, @community, @strName, @strChief )

    INSERT INTO KNIGHTS_USER ( sIDNum, strUserID  ) 
    VALUES   (@index,  @strChief )

    IF @@ERROR <> 0
    BEGIN    
        ROLLBACK TRAN 
        SET @nRet =  6
        RETURN
    END

--  UPDATE USERDATA SET Knights = @index, Fame = 1 WHERE strUserId = @strChief  -- 1 == Chief Authority

    IF @@ERROR <> 0
    BEGIN    
        ROLLBACK TRAN 
        SET @nRet =  6
        RETURN
    END

COMMIT TRAN
SET @nRet =  0
```

The problem is when the stored procedure is called it passes the value of sClanID to bRet which is something I found by executing the statement directly on the SQL server (2008 R2) because when I directly executing like;

```
exec CREATE_KNIGHTS 15001, 2, 1, "OpenKO", 'test'
```

it tries to convert char (OpenKO) to tinyint, and if I give a number as strName instead of OpenKO, it says procedure expects a parameter to @strChief, which was not supplied.

I have other functions with the same structure and they are perfectly fine in the manner of taking parameters correctly and returning the output but why does it not ? and How can I solve this ?

If you like you can see the whole project on [github](http://github.com/srmeier/KnightOnline)

For SEO to this question, as I mentioned below, If I enter the sClanID as words, it gives the error "Error converting data type char to tinyint" and if I enter numbers, it gives "expects parameter @statement, which was not supplied"

Comment: Maybe you should use this `DECALRE @nRet smallint; exec CREATE_KNIGHTS @nRet = @nRet OUTPUT, 15001, 2, 1, 'OpenKO', 'test'; SELECT @nRet;`

Comment: @gofr1 while testing the stement, what you said is probably much better but I'm tracing on SQL server Profiler and the code enters the satement as "exec CREATE_KNIGHTS 15001, 2, 1, "OpenKO", 'test''"

Comment: I didn't say that it is much better :) it is a common way to execute SP with output parameter. have you tried it through SSMS?  Another question, why you use " instead if ' with OpenKO?

Comment: @gofr1 yes I tried through SSMS as I mentioned in the question. I couldn't understand your 2 question.

Comment: You show your exec statement and there "OpenKO" and it needs to be 'OpenKO'. Quotes! And the code from my first command, did you try it?

Comment: @gofr1 I know it should 'OpenKO', but I just did a typo while writing the question.Yes, I tried if I edit it like; ` DECLARE @nRet smallint; exec CREATE_KNIGHTS @nRet OUTPUT, 15001, 2, 1, 'OpenKO', 'test'; SELECT @nRet; it works' `

Comment: So, you need to call your SP in same way with one more parameter. [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378108(v=sql.110).aspx) is some info.

Comment: Ok, it might work, but why does this problem occur ? I have similar functions in the code  and SPs in the database and they are working fine.

Comment: As was posted in answer, output parameters always should be in the end of parameters declaration, in that case you SP will run ok.

Comment: @gofr1 but as I've written on the comments to that answer, it didn't work.

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad! I missed that he didn't pass anything on that part, but he should pass there something to get it work.

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is putting OUTPUT parameters declaration always at the end, and call SP with parameter names.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CREATE_KNIGHTS]
@index      smallint,
@nation     tinyint,
@community  tinyint,
@strName    char(21), 
@strChief   char(21),
@nRet       smallint OUTPUT
```

The following statement should change like that;

```
if (!dbCommand->Execute(string_format(_T("{CALL CREATE_KNIGHTS ( %d, %d, %d, ?, ?, ?)}"), sClanID, bNation, bFlag)))
```

And the code should be like this;

```
    dbCommand->AddParameter(SQL_PARAM_INPUT, strKnightsName.c_str(), strKnightsName.length());
    dbCommand->AddParameter(SQL_PARAM_INPUT, strChief.c_str(), strChief.length());
    dbCommand->AddParameter(SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT, &bRet);
```

Comment: but the structure for calling a stored procedure through ODBC is {? = CREATE_KNIGHTS (...)}, so how can I put it at the end ?

Comment: @Leth just reorder the sequence. I will update my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: in this form , it gives the error  CREATE_KNIGHTS expects parameter @nRet, which was not supplied

Comment: I edited the answer.In this form, it is also working.

Answer (score 0):

Although I managed to solve my question, I won't accept my own answer since I'm looking an answer according to its cause.

I solved it by just giving the first parameter as bRet to the ODBC command, so the last version of the code was;

```
int8 CDBAgent::CreateKnights(uint16 sClanID, uint8 bNation, string & strKnightsName, string & strChief, uint8 bFlag)
{
    int8 bRet = -1;
    unique_ptr<OdbcCommand> dbCommand(m_GameDB->CreateCommand());
    if (dbCommand.get() == nullptr)
        return bRet;


    dbCommand->AddParameter(SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT, &bRet);
    dbCommand->AddParameter(SQL_PARAM_INPUT, strKnightsName.c_str(), strKnightsName.length());
    dbCommand->AddParameter(SQL_PARAM_INPUT, strChief.c_str(), strChief.length());

    if (!dbCommand->Execute(string_format(_T("{? = CALL CREATE_KNIGHTS (%d, %d, %d, %d, ?, ?)}"), bRet, sClanID, bNation, bFlag)))
        ReportSQLError(m_GameDB->GetError());


    return bRet;
}
```

Since, the problem caused because there was a parameter shift while passing the values to the SP, just passing a initial value the OUTPUT variable solved the problem.